# Возврат случайного числа из массива исходя из вероятности

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Здравствуйте.
Имеется массив целых неотрицательных чисел. Необходимо написать функцию, которая вернет случайное число из массива, при этом для конкретного числа вероятность того, что функция вернет его, должна быть тем выше, чем меньше это число.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь алгоритм для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть есть числа `v1, v2, .. vn` с вероятностями появления `p1, p2, .. pn`, Причем `p1 + p2 + .. + pn = 1`. Тогда достаточно сгенерировать случайное число на полуинтервале [0..1) и посмотреть в какой полуинтервал [p(k-1)..p(k)) оно попадет. Тогда будем считать, что выпало число `vk`

```c
double rnd(double * v, double * p, int len) {
  double x = rand();
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += p[i];
    if (x < sum)
      return v[i];
  }
  return v[len - 1];
}
```

Исходя из условия

> для конкретного числа вероятность того, что функция вернет его, должна быть тем выше, чем меньше это число.

массив p формируется так

```c
void fillProb(double * v, double * p, int len) {
  sort(v);
  double prev = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    double cur = (v[i] - v[0])/(v[len - 1] - v[0]);
    p[i] = 1 - (cur - prev);
    prev = cur;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но конкретно в этой задаче вероятности не рассчитаны, а как их рассчитать я не знаю.

Comment: @h86C1p я указал как

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант (для целых чисел, можно для дробных, разница небольшая):

```
int rand(int[] list)
    int max = max(list) + 1
    int sum = 1
    for (int x: list)
        sum+= max - x
    int rand = rand()%sum
    for (int x: list)
        rand -= max - x 
        if (rand <= 0) return x
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что массив должен быть отсортирован?

Comment: @h86C1p не обязательно